AC Unit Delay Start - Is it contactor?
I have my upstairs AC unit acting up recently. Previously the AC unit used to start instantaneously as soon as thermostat sends the cool signal or if we manually change it from off to cool. But lately, it takes about 3-5 minutes for the AC unit to turn on. What could be the reason?
I thought it could be the capacitor so I replaced it with a brand new capacitor. The problem still persists.
Is it a bad contactor? Do you guys advise me to replace the contactor as well? I haven't checked the voltage across the thermostat output voltage at the AC unit. When I turn the AC to cold, the contactor does not turn on instantaneously so I am thinking it is the contactor but I heard contactors rarely go faulty.
Once it turns on after the 3-5 minutes, it blows cold air and everything is good to go. Should I be worried about the delayed start?
Please help me.

Troubleshooting by replacing parts till it works can get expensive.  It can be anything from loose/dirty connections to something wearing out.  Check/test parts first.  contactor points can get pitted, but usually easy to see.

check the 24 volt transformer output

Is it being asked to start frequently, with a short time from last "off" to next "on"?

Fairly common to have a "delay on start" when the system has been powered off and doesn't know if you just flipped the breaker, or it's been not running for hours. Also typical if the compressor stopped, but less than 5 minutes have passed (with the system powered up.)
